# JCL SETTING PARM VALUE WITHIN AN IF

Tags: if-statement, jcl

I have a parm defined at the top of the proc. 'CONDSET'.
Depending on the outcome of the step ARSSS030, I want to alter the parm.
I attempted the following. But the end result is that CONDSET is always set to '103'.
I guess you can't do a parm set within an if???
I even added an iefbr14 following each set statement, so that I could verify the executed steps in the jes msg log. For my testing ARSSS030 RC is 4, but the parm is always set to the last if. In this case '103'. If I comment out the last if/set, then the parm is set to '102'. The OS just uses the 'last' set statement.

```
//  IF ARSSS030.RC = 4 THEN
//      SET CONDSET=101
// ENDIF
//*
// IF ARSSS030.RC = 8 THEN
//     SET CONDSET= 102
// ENDIF
//*
// IF ARSSS030.RC = 12 THEN
//     SET CONDSET= 103
// ENDIF
```

I was hoping that the jcl/if statement would control the parm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

No, you can't. `SET` statements are processed *before* the job is started in the JES Conversion Phase (see below).

## Detailed answer

A *job* on z/OS is processed in six phases:

- Input
- Conversion
- Execution
- Output
- Hard copy
- Purge
  [image]

### Input Phase

This is when the job's `JCL` is handed over to the *Job Entry Subsystem* (JES), i.e. when the job is *submitted*. (Note, there are two different packages: *JES2*, and *JES3*. The differences are minor today, and don't matter for this discussion.)

The `JCL` is written to the *JES Spool*, an intermediate storage on disk. At the same time, a *hanlde* for the job is put on the *Conversion Queue*. This ends the submit.

### Conversion Phase

The JES *Conversion/Interpreter* routine picks a job from the conversion queue, and reads the associated `JCL` from the JES Spool.

The JCL is verified for correct syntax, "missing" parts are amended, i.e. copied into the JCL stream. "Missing parts" are predefined `JCL` statements, which reside in separate JCL Libraries. The `EXEC PROC=`, and the `INCLUDE` statements denote such parts to be copied in.

Variables - called *JCL Symbols*, and *System Symbols* - are also dereferenced in this phase. Some statements such as the `//  SET` statement are resoved at this stage.

The final `JCL` is then written back to the *JES spool*, and if there was no error, the `JCL` is converted into an internal "executable" format, which is also written to the spool.

- If no error was detected, the *job's handle* is placed onto the execution queue.
- If there are errors, then the handle is placed on the output queue.

This end conversion/interpretation for the current job. The process picks the next job from the queue, if any.

### Execution Phase

Jobs on z/OS are executed by a z/OS component known as *Initiator*. There usually are many *initiators* running on a single z/OS instance.

An initiator picks one job from the *Execution Queue*, and runs the job step by step. Note: The JCL has been finalised in the conversion phase; the initiator only reads the fixed, internal representation.

Jobs in execution, more precisely programs run in the different *job steps*  may use system resources, especially read and write to peripheral devices, such as disks, and tapes. They may also read *data records* that were submitted with the `JCL` stream, aka *SYSIN* data, and the may write output to the JES spool, aka *SYSOUT* data.

After the last step of the job has finished execution, the initiator hands over the job to JES, again. The job's handle is placed on the *Output Queue*. The initiator picks the next job from the execution queue, if any.

### Output Phase

JES processes jobs on the *Output Quene*, i.e. jobs that have ended. This phase prepares the various output items which may reside on the JES Spool, and marks then either to be kept waiting for further action, or for *hard copy* processing, or for deletion. The job's handle is the placed on the *Hard Copy Queue*, if at least one output has been marked so, else the handle is directly placed onto the *Purge Queue*.

### Hard Copy Phase

Another type of JES processors (i.e. programs) work on a job's output marked for hardcopy processing. Output might have to be printed, either locally or on a remote print destination. An output might have to be archived. It may have to be transferred to another location for further processing. Probably no longer today, but in the past, it might have to be punched.

The job resides on this queue until all parts have been procesed accordingly. Then the job's handle is placed on the final queue, the *Purge Queue*.

### Purge Phase

JES purges, i.e. deletes, all fragments of this job from the JES spool. The job no longer exists in the system.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I tried searching thru IBM docs, but sometimes it's hard to find what you are looking for. I've done JCL for 40 years, but my current project is straying a bit from the 'old'. Thank you again.